# Custom event Phonegap Jellybean

Tags: javascript, cordova, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I created an app that works fine on iOS and on all android devices except for ones running Jellybean. I've tested on a Nexus 7, a Nexus 5 and a Galaxy Note 3 (KitKat) and it works fine. However when I tried it on a Galaxy Note 2, Galaxy Note 3, and Galaxy S3 all running Jellybean I got the same errors:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Illegal constructor:82
Uncaught Error: UNSPECIFIED_EVENT_TYPE_ERR: DOM Events Exception 0: 71
```

On line 82 I have:

```
var a = new window.Event(trigger);
```

and on Line 71 I have:

```
elem.dispatchEvent(a);
```

This app is completely web based and has no native plugins. So when I open the webpage on the browser, everything works fine on the Jellybean phones. However, once the same code is wrapped in phonegap I start seeing the errors. What is the proper way to create custom javascript events for Jellybean?

Update:
I have found the answer. For jellybean you must use the depreciated method outlined here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createEvent

```
// Create the event.    
var event = document.createEvent('Event');

// Define that the event name is 'build'.
event.initEvent('build', true, true);

// Listen for the event.
document.addEventListener('build', function (e) {
  // e.target matches document from above
}, false);

// target can be any Element or other EventTarget.
document.dispatchEvent(event);
```

Comment: Though I am not aware of how to solve this particular issue, I can explain why it's happening (and maybe that can help). The webview in the Android SDK is not the same as the browser on the device. The SDK webview is usually older as it does not get updated until a newer version of the SDK is released. This why it works in the browser of the Jellyean device but not natively. You can probably search for the webview capabilities of Jellybean and find an alternative method to use for creating events.